# How can i open my front camera in 12.10?

Tags: camera, application-submission

I'm using ubuntu 12.10. I'm unable to open front camera. How can i open front camera? Tell me from scratch. What packages i have to download? Please guide me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just install cheese. Or any other webcam program.

As for "opening" the front camera, i suggest a screwdriver would work just fine, preferrably with a cross point. You don't need any packages for that.

Answer (score 0):

Cheese is a nice app for a camera. It does require GNOME, but it comes with GNOME if you install GNOME. I'll think of some more ways to open the camera.